# Proving if $f$ is integrable on $A$ and $B, A\subseteq B\subseteq\Bbb R^2,$ then $f$ is integrable on $B\setminus A,$

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, proof-writing

> Let $A\subseteq B\subseteq\Bbb R^2.$ If $f:B\to\Bbb R$ is integrable both on $A$ and $B,$ then $f$ is also integrable on $B\setminus A.$

**My thoughts:**

**EDIT:**

I realized my work was wrong and not in accordance to the definition.

> Let $f:A\subset\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$ be a bounded function on a bounded set $A,$ let $B\supseteq A$ be a rectangle and let $\tilde f$ denote the extension by $0$ of $f$ on $B$. We say $f$ is integrable on $A$ if $\tilde f$ is integrable on $B$ and we define $\int_Af=\int_B\tilde f.$

In this case, $f\chi_B$ and $f\chi_A$ are integrable by assumption. By the additivity of the integral, so is the function $f_{\mid B\setminus A}=f\chi_{B\setminus A}=f\chi_B-f\chi_A$ and $$\int_{B\setminus A}f=\int_Bf\chi_{B\setminus A}=\int_Bf-\int_Af$$
The Lebesgue theorem in my script was stated for a function defined on a rectangle, while these sets are arbitrary.

Comment: $+ \infty > \int_{B} |f| = \int_A |f| + \int_{B - A} |f| > \int_{B-A} |f|$

Comment: @undefined, one cannot write that without proving $f\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{\text{ is}}}}$ integrable on $B\setminus A.$

Comment: So what is your question? If a subset of a set of Lebesgue measure zero has Lebesgue measure zero?